# Precision errors in Scala iterate and range

Tags: scala, collections, precision

I'm trying to build a collection of Doubles that has a range and a step. When I use the `Array.iterate` method I get strange floating point errors like such:

```
scala> Array.iterate[Double](0.0, 10)(0.1+)
res0: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999)
```

It seems odd that a small range with a small step would cause such imprecision. I'm aware there are other ways I could do this (e.g. `Array.iterate[Int](0, 10)(1+).map(i => i.toDouble / 10.0)`) but I'm baffled that a built in collection method would perform so badly. Is there a reason for this or am I being a dolt and doing it the wrong way?

Comment: how is this not expected behavior? Try running `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` in REPL, you'll get `0.30000000000000004`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using BigDecimal:

```
scala> val r = BigDecimal(0) to BigDecimal(1) by BigDecimal(0.1)

scala> println(r)
NumericRange(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)
```

Comment: While is neat that you can use `BigDecimal` in ranges like this, it is really just sweeping the underlying issue under the rug (those `BigDecimal` instances are just printing differently than the regular decimal, the error is still there).

Comment: Interesting, thanks @evan058 . Out of curiosity is there a way to actually combat the error rather than "sweeping it under the rug"?

Comment: Use a `Rational` numbers class if possible, otherwise a threshold like `BigDecimal` is doing. I _highly_ recommend you check out at least one of the articles I posted in my answer, understanding the limitations of floating point numbers is absolutely essential

Comment: Note on `BigDecimal`: `scala> val a = BigDecimal(.1) + BigDecimal(.2)  ==>  a: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.3` but then `scala> a.isExactDouble
res14: Boolean = false`. See definition of [`isExactDouble`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/math/BigDecimal.html#isExactDouble:Boolean).

Comment: Great - thanks a lot! I'll check out your articles too

Answer (score 4):

This is a symptom of a fundamental limitation of floating point arithmetic and has nothing to do with collections:

```
scala> 0.2 + 0.1
res0: Double = 0.30000000000000004
```

There are many posts explaining why this happens:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [Why are floating point calculations so inaccurate?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm)
- [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)